Is divergence of a curl not 0 in this case/problem?

Q . A hemispherical shell is placed on the $x$-$y$ plane centered at the origin. For a vector
field $\vec E = (-y\hat e_x +x\hat e_y)/(x²+y²),$ the value of the integral $\int_s (\vec \nabla ×\vec E). \vec {da}$ over the
hemispherical surface is………………$\pi$ .

The correct answer is 2 .
But Why it is not 0 ?. Because here is how i did it-
Using Gauss divergence theorem i can write that integral as-
$$\iiint \vec \nabla. (\vec\nabla × \vec E) dV $$ and since divergence of curl is always zero final answer should be zero.
I do realise that the curl of $\vec E$ is not zero only at origin but how does that affect the statement that "divergence of curl is always 0"- if this statement is always true i think my answer is not wrong.

The point of the exercise is precisely to get students to realise that "div curl = 0" is true except when you have singularities. Those singularities change the answer to what it needs to be.

While researching the question i found in so many sites derivations proving that divergence of a curl is always 0. So i took it for granted, now as i understand it, where could i find some work talking about how its not true in case of singularities?


you should compute the integral for yourself and check that it is non-zero. 2) Differential geometry, at least differential forms, will cover that part of the theory. The part you are seeing is the equivalent of the celebrated Residue theorem.


The Divergence Theorem is not relevant. Stokes's Theorem appears to be the relevant theorem, except for the issue that the vector field is not everywhere continuously differentiable on the hemispherical shell; indeed, it is not defined where the $z$-axis meets the shell. It is a misleading question. They want you to turn the flux integral into a line integral around the boundary curve (which will famously give $2\pi$). But the question does not actually make sense unless you interpret the curl as a vector field with singularities.

The reason i used divergence theorem is because it's the first thing that came to my mind for whatever reason and it indeed provided with an answer though it might be wrong, i just wanted to know why its wrong, which i have understood from the Answer to this question


Is divergence of a curl not 0 in this case/problem?

The divergence of a curl is always zero where it is defined. More specifically, if a vector field $\mathbf A$ is twice-differentiable at a point $\mathbf x$, then $\mathrm{div}\big(\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf A)\big) = 0$ at $\mathbf x$. However, your $\mathbf E$ is not twice-differentiable along the $\hat z$-axis - it's not even well-defined there. And if a function is not defined at some point, its derivatives certainly aren't defined there.

Using Gauss divergence theorem i can write that integral as [...]

Check your assumptions. The divergence theorem says that on a compact region $R$ with boundary $\partial R$,
$$\int_R \nabla \cdot \mathbf F\ \mathrm dV = \int_{\partial R} (\hat{\mathbf n}\cdot \mathbf F)\ \mathrm dS$$
provided that $\mathbf F$ is continuously differentiable in some open set containing $R$. Your $\nabla \times \mathbf E$ violates this assumption quite badly because it isn't even defined over all of $R$.

I do realise that the curl of $\vec E$ is not zero only at origin but how does that affect the statement that "divergence of curl is always 0"- if this statement is always true i think my answer is not wrong.

If the curl of a vector field doesn't even exist, then saying that its divergence is zero is both incorrect and meaningless. If a function is undefined at a point, its derivatives are undefined at that point. Implicit in basically all mathematical statements of this kind is the assumption that the functions you're talking about exist in the first place.
